# access data from a record in a discriminated union

Tags: list, f#, record, discriminated-union

Having this setup, how do I loop through list and print data about each employee?

```
type Person =
    { first_name: string
      last_name: string
      age: int
      salary_hour: int }

type Employee =
    | Administrator of Person
    | OfficeWorker of Person
    | WarehouseWorker of Person


let emps =
    [ Administrator
        { first_name = "name"
          last_name = "name"
          age = 19
          salary_hour = 200 }]
```

Comment: you write a function printemployee that prints an employee, which will differ between each of the 3 cases. then simply call emps |> List.map printemployee or List.iter printemployee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, I'd recommend breaking this into pieces.

Start with a function for each portion, such as a function to print each person (or convert to string, which is often easier to reuse and compose), then a second function that uses that to convert an employee to a string.

Finally, you can use `List.iter` to iterate your list to print:

```
let personToString p =
    sprintf "%s %s [%d] - Salary %d" p.first_name p.last_name p.age p.salary_hour
    
let employeeToString e =
    match e with
    | Administrator a -> sprintf "Administrator: %s" (personToString a)
    | OfficeWorker o -> sprintf "Office: %s" (personToString o)
    | WarehouseWorker w -> sprintf "Warehouse: %s" (personToString w)
    
emps |> List.iter (fun e -> employeeToString e |> printfn "%s")
```